# What is the best practice to manage the version of my android app?

Tags: android

Actually my app is nearly so far, that some people can test it. Now I want to a version number for the app. Where should I put the the version.properties or is there a built-in mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your Manifest you should have this:

```
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks with your advice i found this http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html which makes it also clearer

Answer (score 29):

As to best practices, you can use a very nice approach to manage version code and name described here https://web.archive.org/web/20161206025623/https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/6f5TcVPRZij (use reader view if you see only a blank page) by Jake Wharton.

Basically, you can update your build.gradle to generate versionCode and versionName based on your major, minor and patch version numbers. (Code copied from the link for convenience.)

```
def versionMajor = 3
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Referring to @GregoryK answer, there is am important thing that need to be mentioned.

The difference of 0 zero between each section allows max value of 9 for the **minor** & **patch** values.

(build is limited to 99 which is fine if not used in a CI/CD environment)

The values 3.0.10.0 and 3.1.0.0 will result to the same versionCode when clearly the 2nd is "bigger".
The biggest problem here, is that GooglePlay will refuse to accept the 3.1.0.0 if 3.0.10.0 was uploaded because the version code already exist.

In order to solve the above we need to follow the two zeros (00) space like the build and the patch (patch can be increased until 99):

```
versionMajor * 1000000 + versionMinor * 10000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
```

I recommend this article: 
https://medium.com/@maxirosson/versioning-android-apps-d6ec171cfd82

I end up adopting his build.gradle to something that fits our needs. I added a build code at the end like in the example I gave that is based on @GregoryK answer.

Answer (score 1):

in your project, Gradle file versionCode will be an integer value and versionName could be any kind of text that you can recognize.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

versionCode is your apk subsequent release number, where a release is what going to be published in Google Play

Answer (score 0):

one thing that is missing in all these answers is version code for multiple apks.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#VersionCodes

We suggest using a version code with at least 7 digits: integers that represent the supported configurations are in the higher order bits, and the version name (from android:versionName) is in the lower order bits. For example, when the application version name is 3.1.0, version codes for an API level 4 APK and an API level 11 APK would be something like 0400310 and 1100310, respectively. The first two digits are reserved for the API Level (4 and 11, respectively), the middle two digits are for either screen sizes or GL texture formats (not used in these examples), and the last three digits are for the application's version name (3.1.0).